Analyzing poly-py-eip712-structs and converting it to vb.net. Where is _encode_value implemented in EIP712Domain?
If I look at
https://github.com/Polymarket/poly-py-eip712-structs/blob/main/poly_eip712_structs/domain_separator.py
The class
EIP712Domain inherit from EIP712Struct which inherit from EIP712Type
Class EIP712Type has a mustinherit method
def _encode_value(self, value) -> bytes:
    """Must be implemented by subclasses, handles value encoding on a case-by-case basis.

    Don't call this directly - use ``.encode_value(value)`` instead.
    """
    pass

But EIP712Domain  doesn't inherit it anywhere
What am I missing?
My current solution after consulting ChatGPT and using a bit of common sense is this
Public Class EIP712Domain
    Inherits EIP712Struct

    Public Shared DefaultDomain As EIP712Domain = Nothing

    ' Define properties with nullable types since fields are optional
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Version As String
    Public Property ChainId As Nullable(Of UInteger)
    Public Property VerifyingContract As String
    Public Property Salt As Byte()  ' Assuming Salt is a 32-byte array

    ' Constructor that initializes fields based on the provided parameters
    Public Sub New(Optional name As String = Nothing,
                   Optional version As String = Nothing,
                   Optional chainId As Nullable(Of UInteger) = Nothing,
                   Optional verifyingContract As String = Nothing,
                   Optional salt As Byte() = Nothing)

        ' Validate that at least one argument is provided
        If name Is Nothing AndAlso version Is Nothing AndAlso
           chainId Is Nothing AndAlso verifyingContract Is Nothing AndAlso
           salt Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("At least one argument must be given.")
        End If

        ' Conditionally assign values based on provided arguments
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Version = version
        Me.ChainId = chainId
        Me.VerifyingContract = verifyingContract
        Me.Salt = salt
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function _EncodeValue(value As Object) As Byte()
        Dim encodedFields As New List(Of Byte())

        ' Encode each field based on its type if it's not Nothing.
        If Name IsNot Nothing Then
            encodedFields.Add((New StringType()).EncodeValue(Name))
        End If

        If Version IsNot Nothing Then
            encodedFields.Add((New StringType()).EncodeValue(Version))
        End If

        If ChainId IsNot Nothing Then
            encodedFields.Add((New UintType(256)).EncodeValue(ChainId))
        End If

        If VerifyingContract IsNot Nothing Then
            encodedFields.Add((New AddressType()).EncodeValue(VerifyingContract))
        End If
        If Salt IsNot Nothing Then
            encodedFields.Add((New BytesType(32)).EncodeValue(Salt))
        End If

        ' Concatenate the encoded fields into a single byte array
        Dim concatenated As Byte() = encodedFields.SelectMany(Function(b) b).ToArray()

        ' Hash the concatenated fields
        Return Keccak(concatenated)
    End Function
End Class

Am I doing it right?
The thing is the _encode_value for the python version is not implemented anywhere and I have looked that up. So chatgpt gave me what most likely is the right implementation.
Another thing that may work is to just do
Protected Overrides Function _EncodeValue(value As Object) As Byte()
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
    'This shouldn't be called
End Function

It's a protected class. It shouldn't be called and EIP712Struct implement encode_value (without _) that encode the content of "self" and value is not even used anymore.
